# PowerApps - Hide a Button if current user = created by

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, formula

I have a PowerApps form (customized from SP list).  I need to only have a Submit button visible if the Current User is the creator (created by field in SP).  Basically, I only want the person submitting the new form to see the button.  Others will go back into the form and add content/approve...I don't want them to see the button.

I added the Created By field (datacardvalue49) to the form from SP, and I'm trying to reference it, but not sure how.  I tried If(datacardvalue49 = User().FullName, true, false).  I know I'm missing something after the datacardvalue (choice fields are ".selected.value", text fields are ".text"), but I'm not sure what that suffix would be.

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *show* the button based on condition, set "Visible" property of button control to:

```
User().Email = ThisItem.'Created By'.Email
```

OR

```
User().Email = datacardvalue49.Selected.Email
```

If you want to compare based on display name, use:

```
User().FullName = datacardvalue49.Selected.DisplayName
```

---

To *hide* button you can use `<>` or `Not()` like:

```
User().FullName <> datacardvalue49.Selected.DisplayName
```

OR

```
Not(User().FullName = datacardvalue49.Selected.DisplayName)
```