# Hiding the field/data card from everyone but the user who created the item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, formula

I would like to hide a data card from everyone but the user who created the item and have been using this code:

```
If(ThisItem.'Created By'.Email = User().Email, true, false)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where are you adding this formula, inside form/gallery control or somewhere else? You have to set this formula on `Visible` property of control.

Comment: Check this thread, let me know if it works for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304389/powerapps-hide-a-button-if-current-user-created-by/304390#304390

Comment: Hi @NK711, did you try my solution given below? Is it working for you?

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *show* the control based on condition, set "Visible" property of control to:

```
User().Email = ThisItem.'Created By'.Email
```

OR based on dropdown:

```
User().Email = datacardvalue49.Selected.Email
```

If you want to compare based on display name, use:

```
User().FullName = datacardvalue49.Selected.DisplayName
```

---

To *hide* button you can use `<>` or `Not()` like:

```
User().FullName <> datacardvalue49.Selected.DisplayName
```

OR

```
Not(User().FullName = datacardvalue49.Selected.DisplayName)
```